# How much of a difference can a few ohm make?

Tags: resistors

So I kinda messed my project up a bit and instead of putting 0207 resistor footprints I used 0204 - Because I lack the time to wait for a new board because I still need to test it I just go with 0204 instead - test it and order with a better layout while fixing problems.
But I won't get all the resistors in the size I need in my local store.

Some are fine, like a resistor for a LED. If I put a higher one, the light just isn't that bright anymore - that's okay.

But in this project I also have some pre-defined resistors for MCUs:
I use a [LAN8720](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/00002165b.pdf) where RBIAS Pin needs a 12k1 to GND and 49.9 on the TX/RX pins stated in the datasheet but I can't get this in my local store and order/shipping takes to long. Now I have the choice to take a 12K or 15K for the RBIAS and either 47 oder 52 for the TX/RX pins.

Would that make much of a difference for these?

Comment: These are in range of common %2 error of a typical resistor. How that's gonna make a (important) difference?

Comment: It's quite a rare combination to have THT resistors and an IC with a 50 MHz data bus that must be soldered in an oven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your direct question: Replacing 12.1 with 12 and 49.9 with 52 is unlikely to have *any* effect that you can measure without expensive instruments. They even list 12k in their application note in the datasheet. If this is a one-off project or even a small series, just go ahead and use what you can get. Worst case you will find that you can only use 90 metre cables if the temperature is above 70 °C, but I doubt you will even have that.

However, if this is a small series, you should easily be able to fit a 0207 resistor into a 0204 footprint. They'll have worse mechanical stress tolerance, and it's obviously bad for automated production, but for hand placed component it should work well enough.

Comment: I see - Thanks. Well currently its just the first real prototype. If it works I will make a "pretty" and better one might even switch to SMD. Yes I was thinking of fitting 0207 into the 0204 but that looks kind of ugly and doesn't fit on most places if I just want them "flat" - I thought about doimg them vertical but I heard that easly can make a antenna especially in the lan region which seems bad.

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer specified 1% resistors in those places for a reason. You can't just substitute 5% resistors and expect the same level of design margin and reliability.

However, for preliminary evaluation of your prototypes, it will probably work well enough. 12k is within 1% of 12k1, so just use your multimeter to make sure they're really 12k before you install them.

For the 49r9 terminators, you'd probably be better off stacking two 100r resistors in parallel on each site. Again, measure them for accuracy before using them.